# How to add Custom Button under the price box in Product add/edit form in Magento 2.4 Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, magento2.4, product-edit

**I want to add a button under the price box on the product add/edit admin form and call a custom controller function when click on it by AJAX request.**

Please Help ....!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create product attribute to add desired field
[Magento 2 Add Product Attribute Programmatically](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html)

Comment: I want to add a Button, not the input text.

Comment: You cannot create a button on the product page. Magento only allows you to create more attributes for products, you can't create and save according to your customizations